# Iterate over a string and fill an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I'm working on this code that iterates over a string--that is actually a string representing an integer in this case--and fills an array with each "digit" of the string.  So string `"350"` would result in an array with elements `{3,5,0}`.
Here is the code:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
      int arr[5];
        string test = "10000";
      for(unsigned int i = 0; i<test.length(); i++) {
        char c = test[i]; 
        cout << c << endl;
        arr[i] = c;

    }
    //printing the array for testing
    for (int i = 5 - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        cout << arr[i];
        return 0;
    }
     char c = test[i]; 
            arr[i] = c;
        }
            return 0;
    }
```

The issue is that array that results from this is `{49,48,48,48,48}`.  I have no idea why its doing that and where I have gone wrong with the code.  Why is it adding the numbers 49 and 48, and how can I fix this?

Also if it helps anyone, here is a link to a stepper running through the code:
http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%0A%23include%20%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%23include%20%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0A%0Ausing%20namespace%20std%3B%0A%0A%0A%0Aint%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20int%20arr%5B5%5D%3B%0A%09string%20test%20%3D%20%2210000%22%3B%0A%20%20for%28unsigned%20int%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%3Ctest.length%28%29%3B%20i%2B%2B%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20char%20c%20%3D%20test%5Bi%5D%3B%20//this%20is%20your%20character%0A%20%20%20%20arr%5Bi%5D%20%3D%20c%3B%0A%7D%0A%09return%200%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=19&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=cpp&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: Or pull yourself out of the last century and use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). Or just character literal math. Since the digit character encodings are guaranteed sequential per the standard, `test[i] - '0'` would give you the corresponding single-digit `int` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in your array are the ascii for the characters your insert.
Here is what you should do to convert your character to an integer:
`arr[i] = atoi(&c);`

Comment: `atoi` accepts a [edit: null-terminated] string (and also doesn't differentiate between a failure and 0).

Comment: I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me.  So 4 more minutes :)

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!

Comment: the current code is not very c++-ish, perhaps `std::transform(test.begin(),test.end(),arr,[](char c){return c-'0';});` would do better

Answer (score 1):

The 48 and 49 are your 0 and 1 in ascii.  You need to convert from ascii to digits.

Answer (score 0):

You created `arr` as an array of integers, thus by assigning character elements to it you implicitly cast them to an integer. When you do this, the ASCII value of the characters is printed, instead of the characters themselves. You should use an array of characters instead.

```
char arr[5];
```